# How to fill OpenVDB voxels that are inside a given plane?

Tags: c++, voxels, openvdb

I have a quad defined by 4 (x,y,z) points (like a plane that has edges). I have an OpenVDB grid. I want to fill all the voxels with value 1 that are inside my quad (including edges). Is such thing possible with out setting each voxel of the quad (limited plane) manually?

Answer (score 1):

If the four points build a rectangle, it could be possible using the

```
void fill(const CoordBBox& bbox, const ValueType& value, bool active = true);
```

function that exists in the `Grid`-class. It is not possible to transform the `CoordBBox` for rotations, instead you would have to do that by changing the transformation of the grid. With pseudo-code it could look like

```
CoordBBox plane; // created from your points
Transform old = grid.transform();
grid.setTransform(...); // Some transformation that places the grid correctly with respect to the plane
grid.fill(plane, 1);
grid.setTransform(old);
```

If this is not the case, you would have to set the values yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is an unoptimized method, for arbitrarily shaped planar quadrilaterals, you only need to input four vertices of the 3D space plane, and the output is filled planar voxels.

> 1. Get the vertex with the longest sum of adjacent sides as A, the adjacent vertices of A are B and D, and obtain the voxel coordinates and voxel numbers between A-B and A-D based on ray-cast, and in addition A vertex C-B and C-D progressively sample the same number of voxels.
> 2. Make one-to-one correspondence between the voxels adjacent to the two vertices A and D above, and fill the plane area based on ray-cast.

```cpp
void VDBVolume::fillPlaneVoxel(const PlanarEquation& planar) {
  auto accessor = volume_->getUnsafeAccessor();
  const auto transform = volume_->transform();
  const openvdb::Vec3f vdbnormal(planar.normal.x(), planar.normal.y(), planar.normal.z());
  int longside_vtx[2];
  calVtxLongSide(planar.vtx, longside_vtx);
  // 1. ray cast long side
  std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> longsidepoints;
  int neiborvtx[2];
  {
    const Eigen::Vector3f origin = planar.vtx[longside_vtx[0]];
    const openvdb::Vec3R eye(origin.x(), origin.y(), origin.z());
    
    GetRectNeiborVtx(longside_vtx[0], neiborvtx);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      Eigen::Vector3f direction = planar.vtx[neiborvtx[i]] - origin;
      openvdb::Vec3R dir(direction.x(), direction.y(), direction.z());
      dir.normalize();
      const float length = static_cast<float>(direction.norm());
      if(length > 50.f) {
        std::cout << "GetRectNeiborVtx length to large, something wrong: "<< i << "\n" << origin.transpose() << "\n"
                  << planar.vtx[neiborvtx[i]].transpose() << std::endl; 
        continue;
      }
      const float t0 =  -voxel_size_/2;
      const float t1 = length + voxel_size_/2;

      const auto ray = openvdb::math::Ray<float>(eye, dir, t0, t1).worldToIndex(*volume_);
      openvdb::math::DDA<decltype(ray)> dda(ray);
      do {
        const auto voxel = dda.voxel();
        const auto voxel_center_world = GetVoxelCenter(voxel, transform);
        longsidepoints.emplace_back(voxel_center_world);

      } while (dda.step());
    }
  }

  // 2. 在小边均匀采样相同数目点
  const int longsidepointnum = longsidepoints.size();
  std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> shortsidepoints;
  shortsidepoints.resize(longsidepointnum);
  {
    // 输入：顶点、两邻接点，vtxs， 输出采样带年坐标，根据距离进行采样
    GenerateShortSidePoints(longside_vtx[1], neiborvtx, planar.vtx, shortsidepoints);
  }
  // 3. ray cast from longsidepoints to shortsidepoints
  // std::cout << "longsidepointnum: " << longsidepointnum << std::endl;
  for(int pid = 0; pid < longsidepointnum; ++pid) {
    const Eigen::Vector3f origin = longsidepoints[pid];
    const openvdb::Vec3R eye(origin.x(), origin.y(), origin.z());
    const Eigen::Vector3f direction = shortsidepoints[pid] - origin;
    openvdb::Vec3R dir(direction.x(), direction.y(), direction.z());
    dir.normalize();

    const float length = direction.norm();
    if(length > 50.f) {
      std::cout << "length to large, something wrong: "<< pid << "\n" << origin.transpose() << "\n"
                << shortsidepoints[pid].transpose() << std::endl; 
      continue;
    }
    const float t0 =  -voxel_size_/2;
    const float t1 = length + voxel_size_/2;
    const auto ray = openvdb::math::Ray<float>(eye, dir, t0, t1).worldToIndex(*volume_);
    openvdb::math::DDA<decltype(ray)> dda(ray);
    do {
      const auto voxel = dda.voxel();
      accessor.setValue(voxel, vdbnormal);
    } while (dda.step());
  }
}
```